# positioning nodes according to their sizes in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I produced the following output using the `tikz` code shown below. What I want is for the arrow on the right to have a fixed length relative to the rightmost symbol, not relative to the center of the node. How do I accomplish this? I'm new to `tikz`, and could not figure out how to do it using mechanisms like `xshift` or `+(x,y)` coordinates.

Basically I want to be able to specify the position of the right-hand node (tip of the arrow) as something like

```
n0.east+(1em,0)
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}
\pgfsetlayers{edgelayer,nodelayer,main}
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[draw=black,arrows=-latex]

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(n1.base),thick]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
      \node (n0) at (0, 0) {$#1$};           
      \node (n1) at +(2em, 0) {};                  
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
      \draw [style=arrow] (n0) to (n1);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\foo{x}

\foo{xy}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to draw an horizontal arrow with length `1em` starting at `node.east`, you can use `\draw[->] n0.east--++(1em,0)`. If you want a `node` there, you can use `\draw[->] n0.east--++(1em,0) coordinate (n1)`. I think you don't need `calc` library nor so many layers, but may be I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Ignasi: This is very helpful. My example was more complicated than it needed to be. But I think you have an error in syntax; you need parens around the n0.east.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tikz`'s `calc` library for coordinate calculations. So with `usetikzlibrary{calc}` desired coordinate calculation could be performed as:

```
($(n0.east)+(1em,0)$)
```

Alternatively you can apply a shift, which has the advantage that it does not require the `calc` library, as follows

```
([xshift=1em]n0.east)
```

Either of these two methods yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}
\pgfsetlayers{edgelayer,nodelayer,main}
\tikzstyle{arrow}=[draw=black,arrows=-latex]

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(n1.base),thick]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
      \node (n0) at (0, 0) {$#1$};           
      \node (n1) at ([xshift=1em]n0.east) {};                  
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
      \draw [style=arrow] (n0) to (n1);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\foo{x}

\foo{xy}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I needed.